# Google apps script converting date within formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Apps Script to create a new set of tabs within a sheet, and everything is going well apart from one date within a formula. The code I'm using is

```
function MakeANewDaySheet() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
...
...
  spreadsheet.getRange('O2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula("=iferror(indirect(" + date + '!$B3),\"Please select a department\")')
}
```

The formula I want the script to put in the cell points to another sheet that's created during this script, and its name is simply today's date. When the formula is entered using the script it puts ' around the year, which I cant seem to stop it doing.

I'm wanting to use the formula '=iferror(indirect(02/06/2020!$B3),"Please select a department")' 
and its giving me '=iferror(indirect(2/6/'2020'!$B3),"Please select a department")'

I've tried changing around between " and ', including \ and not, hoping it was that easy, but no luck.

Can anyone point out what is probably (hopefully) a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would reference another sheet (tab) with `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&"03/06/2020"&"'!"&"$B3")
```

To set this formula via Apps Script, you have to use the escape character (`\"`) each time a there is double quote in the formula. So you can do this:

```js
var formula = "=IFERROR(INDIRECT(\"'\"&\"" + date + "\"&\"'!\"&\"$B3\"), \"Please select a department\")";
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(formula);
```

#### Note:

Also, if you want to set this formula to `O2`, there is not need to activate the cell first, you can just do this:

```js
spreadsheet.getRange('O2').setFormula(formula);
```

#### Reference:

- [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)

Answer (score 0):

The `indirect` function resolves cell reference written as string but in this case date is not being written as string in the formula. Please try this

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=iferror(indirect("' + date + '" & "!$B3"),"Please select a department")')`

Comment: Thats getting closer to what I need, now the output  in the cell is

`=iferror(indirect("3/6/2020" & "!$B3"),"Please select a department")`
This would be fine except that the indirect function doesn't seem to recognise the sheet value as a sheet when its text. I think I'm going to try casting the date as a string at the start of the function, then inserting that string rather than date.

If you think of anything else in the meantime, please let me know. If not, that's for your help @Alpesh Jain

Comment: Hi Nicky, I have tried it on a test sheet and seems to be working fine. May be you should check if the sheet which you are creating using script has exactly same name as in the formula